# Quarto ggplot2 font sizes increase with chunk option fig.width and layout-ncol

Tags: ggplot2, font-size, chunks, quarto

I use an `#| layout-ncol` option in quarto to place figures side-by-side. However, in combination with the chunk option `fig.width` the font size is changing as well. It seems as if the plot is zoomed in. I am searching for quite some time for a solution but was not able to figure out how to maintain all font sizes at a fixed size. I produced a little example illustrating the problem:

Only difference between first and second chunk is basically the addition of `fig.width=3` in the second chunk.

````
---
format:
  html: 
    theme: default
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.asp=1}
#| layout-ncol: 2
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
x = c(1:10),
y = c(11:20)
)

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(
        size = 10)) +
  ylab("Y-Axis") +
  xlab("X-Axis")

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(
        size = 10)) +
  ylab("Y-Axis") +
  xlab("X-Axis")

```

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.asp=1, fig.width=3}
#| layout-ncol: 2

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(
        size = 10)) +
  ylab("Y-Axis") +
  xlab("X-Axis")

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(
        size = 10)) +
  ylab("Y-Axis") +
  xlab("X-Axis")
```
````

Would be happy for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally just found the answer myself. When using `#| layout-ncol` and no `fig.width` is defined for that chunk, the `ggplot` seems to be rescaled in a way that results in smaller font sizes of the plots text elements. So the solution is just to always define a `fig.width` that fits the respective columns where ggplots are displayed. I think there is a clear explenation for that, but I don't it. :D